# Did the Makers of the Lupin III "Red-Jacket" Series get Permission to Feature Superman?

Tags: copyright, lupin-the-third

In one of the Episodes of the Lupin III part 2 "Red-Jacket" series, Lupin foils a scheme by Fujiko who has henchmen impersonating Superman to rob banks.

I am curious if anyone has any information on whether this was technically allowed by DC, and if so, why?

If it wasn't allowed, then why is Crunchyroll.com able to screen this episode?

Here is the imdb page for the episode. There is another earlier episode of the same series that also mentions Superman.
https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0914728/